# Most accurate method of Voice Activity Detection?

Tags: noise, signal-analysis, signal-detection, voice

What is currently the most accurate Voice Activity Detection algorithm with high levels of background noise? I would also appreciate if it does not require any manual calibration. Bonus points for examples.

EDIT: I am referring to accuracy as yielding the lowest amount of false positives and negatives.

Comment: What sort of background noise? What sort of voices (talking? singing?) ?

Comment: Talking. Ambient background noise.

Comment: As the fact that the question is put on hold, I disagree. Accuracy is a quantitative not qualitative measurement. -_-

Comment: Please re-word (edit) your question to make the accuracy quantitative. What measure are you using?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: I would look at vowel detection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 detectors, you may try blind separation based on the power spectrum difference of voice and background noise

Comment: Define more than 1 detectors? As in stereo vs mono?